# Python Showing:- TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in python While Trying to Run Code

Tags: python, python-2.7

Well, I researched and saw many posts on this but none of them let me fix my code.

I am learning python and is currently learning Object Oriented classes.

This is My Code:-

```
class Employee:
    'Common base calss for all employees'
    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayCount(self):
        print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print "Name: ", self.name, ",Salary: ", self.salary

"This whould create first object of Employee class"
emp1 = Employee("Zara", 2000)
"This whould create second object of employee class"
emp2 = Employee("Manni", 5000)

emp1.displayEmployee()
emp2.displayEmployee()
print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount()
```

And then when I run it:-

```
Name:  Zara ,Salary:  2000
Name:  Manni ,Salary:  5000

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Python Programs/Object Oriented-Classes(Python 2).py", line 46, in 
<module>
print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: your traceback says that, in contrast with your code, `Employee.empCount` is called with the code `Employee.empCount()`.

Comment: Employee.empCount is an int, not a method. So don't try and call it like a method with `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount()
```

to this

```
print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error.

`TypeError : 'int' object is not callable`

You are trying to call a class variable `Employee.empCount` which is an integer and thus cannot be called.

Just change it to `Employee.empCount` and it should print out the varialble.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "Employee.empCount()". Remember, "()" this is used to call functions. 
Like you can do "Employee.displayCount()", because displayCount() is a function.
But to access variables, simply do like this:

```
print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount
```

Comment: Well, I don't know why but I simply didn't see those parentheses. Before I realised this and came here it was already answered.